# Is there no a class in Unity for building navmesh in editor mode in code?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

Earlier, it was NavMeshBuilder, but with version 5.5 there is no such a class.

How can I bake NavMesh in code in editor mode ?

### EDIT 1

I do not want to bake navmesh at runtime.
All I want to do is bake navMesh in editor mode(NOT PLAY MODE) BY THE MY CODE AND NOT BY THE NAVIGATION TAB.
Is it still possible ?
Just call method that builds nav mesh.

Comment: Either I don't get the question or this is what you're looking for https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html

Comment: @JonasGiuro The thing is, that I can bake nav mesh in editor by button in special window. But I need to bake it in code. And earlier, there was such ability with NavMeshBuilder class.

Comment: seems like there's no way of doing it with the build in navmesh system right now: https://unity3d.com/unity/roadmap maybe using a third party solution from the asset store or roll your own would be the way to go.

Comment: You can't bake in runtime, but you can disable your static objects temporarily, bake the navmesh, and then add a navmesh obstacle to your objects and use the carve option which can carve shapes out of the navmesh essentially getting the same result

Comment: It is still there in 5.5 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMesh.html

Comment: Also, without using an example script, it is quite difficult to see what you might be doing wrong or missing.

Comment: Please include the code you tried that did not work in 5.5 that used to work in earlier versions, if you don't your question will likely be closed for not having enough details about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not right in new path of NavMeshBuilder.
I searched for it in UnityEngine.AI but now it in UnityEditor.AI

Comment: All editor specific functions are inside UnityEditor